# How to build a docker image inside Airflow

Tags: docker, airflow, google-cloud-build, docker-build, docker-in-docker

I want to deploy an application to Airflow that accepts a config file as a parameter, pulls the git repository specified by said config, then transforms it into a Docker image, then uploads that image to GCP's Artifact Registry. What is the best practice for building a docker image inside an Airflow DAG?

I have tried orchestrating a manually-triggered cloud build run via Airflow - I have not been able to pass the necessary substitutions into the cloudbuild.yaml file using the CloudBuildCreateBuildOperator, nor have I been able to specify the workspace.

I have also created a docker image that itself can create new docker images (when the docker.sock file is mounted as a volume). However, using a KubernetesPodOperator to call this seems to go against the design philosophy of Airflow, since this task would be affecting the host machine by building new docker images directly on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the responsability of `Airflow` to apply this kind of use case.

`Airflow` is a pipeline and tasks orchestrator based on `DAGs` (direct acyclic graph).

Your need corresponds to usual CI CD pipelines.
It's better to delegate this work on a tool like `Cloud Build` or `Gitlab CI` for example.

From `Cloud Build`, you can apply and automate all the actions specified in your question.

When you will build your image in the CI CD part, you can then in the `Airflow` DAG, use a `Docker` image if needed with `KubernetesPodOperator`.

This would be more coherent because each concern will be put in the right place and on the right tool.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - wouldn't the KubernetesPodOperator be problematic for orchestrating the Cloud Build sequence? Because Kubernetes, to my understanding, could arbitrarily reset ephemeral containers, there is no guarantee that a run would be seen to completion. If it is not completed, the run will both continue and start again, building two docker images, right?

Comment: The `KubernetesPodOperator` will only allows you to execute a task in `Airflow` based on the context of a `Docker` image and container. Example if you want to launch a `Python` script with an isolation of its packages, you can build an image with `Python` and the packages then launch the script. `Cloud Build` is another concern and must be launched separately and not in Airflow.

Comment: Very Good answer @MazlumTosun. And we find here again the issue, and the mix between orchestrator and business processes. c.f. comparison with Workflow.

Comment: Thanks @guillaume-blaquiere, I understand your point, unfortunately many devs don't put the responsibility in the right place and we hope to help them.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere let alone the over complication of what is effectively git hooks with distributed make and POSIX batch processing in cgroup jails.

Answer (score 0):

> best practice for building a docker image inside an Airflow DAG

After seeing code like this at some banks and gig economy companies plus the outstanding headaches to make it work. One can say the best practice is to **not use an ETL batch processing tool for CI/CD** when a streaming and event based processing tool is better. That said, *yes*, airflow can call just about any python module or method, so one can use `dockerpy` to pragmatically build your docker images.

For example:

```
from __future__ import annotations

import logging, sys, time

from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.models.dag import DAG
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.python import PythonVirtualenvOperator, is_venv_installed

default_args = {
  'start_date': days_ago(2),
  'catchup': False,
  'tags': ["cicd","yourname/app"]
}

with DAG(dag_id="cicd_docker_build", schedule_interval='@once,  default_args=default_args) as dag:
    if not is_venv_installed():
        log.error("The virtualenv_python example task requires virtualenv, please install it.")
        sys.exit(1)
        
    @task.virtualenv(task_id="build_docker_image", 
        requirements=["dockerpy"], 
        system_site_packages=False)
    def build_image(**op_kwargs):
        from docker import DockerClient
        from docker.errors import APIError, TLSParameterError
        try:
            docker_host = BaseHook.get_connection('docker_host')
            client = DockerClient(base_url=docker_host.get_uri())
            client.images.build(tag='yourname/app:latest', path ='./')
        except (APIError, TLSParameterError) as err:
            log.error(err)
            sys.exit(1)

    @task.virtualenv(task_id="publish_docker_image", 
        requirements=["dockerpy"],
        system_site_packages=False)
    def push_image(**op_kwargs):
        from docker import DockerClient
        from docker.errors import APIError, TLSParameterError

        try:
            docker_repo = BaseHook.get_connection('docker.io')
            docker_host = BaseHook.get_connection('docker_host')
            client = DockerClient(base_url=docker_host.get_uri())
            client.login(
                username=docker_repo.user,
                password=docker_repo.password,
                registry=docker_repo.hostname)
            client.api.push('yourname/app:latest')
        except (APIError, TLSParameterError) as err:
            log.error(err)
            sys.exit(1)

    build_task = build_image()
    release_task = push_image()

    build_task >> release_task
```

This DAG presumes three things:

1. The runner has docker installed, has the `DOCKER_HOST` setup as a connection named `docker_host`, and the Dockerfile exists next to the dag file
2. You know how to configure airflow to trigger on webhooks and/or scheduled tasks
3. You already have airflow configured and deployed plus added the `docker.io` registry connection

What it does is effectively the same as the shell command: `docker build -t yourname/app:latest . && docker login && docker push yourname/app:latest` or build pack step in cloud build: `pack build docker.io/yourname/app:latest --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base --publish`.

Ways to improve this; use an actual CI/CD tool and since OP is saying Cloud build, just drop a [cloudbuild.yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/blob/master/docker/cloudbuild.yaml) into the repo then use [Terraform's google provider > resources.cloudbuild_trigger](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudbuild_trigger) to build the pipeline. If one *has to* use airflow/python then setup webhooks to trigger the DAG and configure your CICD system to push to the airflow webhook handler plus set up a second DAG just for [google-sdk](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudbuild/latest) to configure cloud build.